# FileSystemWatcher does not notify on deleting the path directory itself

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I am using a FileSystemWatcher in my code to track any change/rename/addition of file under the monitored directory. Now I need a notification if the monitored directory itself gets deleted.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

I was attempting to add a second watcher on the parent directory ( `C:\temp\subfolder1` in the sample below) and filter the events to the fullpath of the monitored directory ( `C:\temp\subfolder1\subfolder2`).

But this won't work if the deletion is done a directory level higher and I do not want to monitor the whole file system. In the sample below it should fire on deleting `C:\temp`  as well, not only on deleting `C:\temp\subfolder1`.

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
      watcher.Path = @"C:\temp\subfolder1\subfolder2";
      watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

      watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
      watcher.Created += OnChanged;
      watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
      watcher.Renamed += OnChanged;

      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The scope of notifications will only be up to the folder path that you specify in the watcher - why would it work for any folders higher up ?

Comment: Well, it can't be deleted.  Your program has a handle opened on the directory object.  Consider that what actually happened is that the directory got moved to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 7):

You can subscribe to the `FileSystemWatcher.Error` Event. This will fire when the parent directory gets deleted. Then you can make the appropriate checks to see if this was caused by the folder deletion.

Answer (score 2):

@crankedrelic Thanks for contributing!
In order to get both deletion cases (permanently and move to recycle bin) I have to use this code:

```
private static void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
{
  Exception ex = e.GetException();
  if (ex is Win32Exception && (((Win32Exception)ex).NativeErrorCode == 5))
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Directory deleted permanently: { watcher.Path }");
  }
}

private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  if (!Directory.Exists(watcher.Path))
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Directory deleted (recycle bin): { watcher.Path }");
  }
}
```